# How to open files through vim editor in cscope?

Tags: linux, vim

I want to open a .c file , that I found using cscope, in vim editor. Normally it opens in vi editor. I have made and edited vimrc file using a configuration that I found online but it isn't working. Can anyone recommend a a proper configuration for vimrc? 
Is there any other way to do it?

Also I am working on my office system, so I am not the super user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cscope` uses the environment variable `EDITOR` for editing files.  If this environment variable is unset, it uses `vi`.

To set `EDITOR` to `vim`, put the following in you shell initialisation file for interactive shells (`$HOME/.bashrc` for `bash` users):

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

You may alternatively use `CSCOPE_EDITOR` instead of `EDITOR` (if you don't want to set `EDITOR`, which may be used by any number of other programs, including the shell, for example). The `CSCOPE_EDITOR` environment variable overrides the `EDITOR` setting.

This is mentioned in the `cscope` manual in the section "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES".

Comment: Hi, I deed as you told but the issue still persists. I tried both CSCPOE_EDITOR  and EDITOR .

Comment: @kaushikchatterjee Note the spelling of `CSCOPE_EDITOR `. These has to be set in the current shell session. Just adding them to `~/.bashrc` will not do anything until you start a new shell.

Comment: Yes its working now. My spelling was right. Once a I edited the `~/.bashrc` file in bash , I opened a new terminal and from there I was running cscope . That was the mistake. Now, I continued within the same bash and its working now. Thanks.